# Set a wordpress cron job to hit a url every 2 minutes

Tags: wordpress, cron, crontrigger

Hi I have a url which imports data from csv to database on wordpress.I want this to run every 2 minutes .Is tried a plugin for this cron job scheduer but this did not work.
How can I write a action script function make this possibe.Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following
First you need to add the 2m interval to the schedule

```
add_filter('cron_schedules', 'my_schedules');

function my_schedules($schedules)
{
    $schedules['once_every_2m'] = array('interval' => 120, 'display' => 'Once every 2 minutes');
    return $schedules;
}
```

Then you add your job using newly created interval

```
if (!wp_next_scheduled('name_of_your_job'))
{
    wp_schedule_event(1481799444, 'once_every_2m', 'name_of_your_job');
}
add_action('name_of_your_job', 'function_that_should_be_executed');

function function_that_should_be_executed()
{
    //do what you need to do
}
```

Also, keep in mind, due to how WP cron works, it might be in accurate with timing. [Docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/)

Comment: @Melvin you can do whatever you need within the function `function_that_should_be_executed`

Comment: Can you give me an example code please . I am blank

Comment: I already gave you an full code. I can't and won't write whole function since I have no idea what you want to do every 2 minutes. You should be able to do what you need within the function.

Comment: i want to hit a url every 2 minutes

Comment: So what's stopping you? Write code to do that within `function_that_should_be_executed` and you'll be good

Comment: The this is a very good opportunity to learn, don't you think? This resource is meant to help you learn, not to ask someone to do your job for you.

Comment: You could use it if it does what you need, yes